# Two ways to check if a list is empty - differences?

Tags: java, list

I have a short question.

Lets assume we have a `List` which is an `ArrayList` called `list`. We want to check if the list is empty.

What is the difference (if there is any) between:

```
if (list == null) { do something }
```

and

```
if (list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

I'm working on an ancient code (written around 2007 by someone else) and it is using the `list == null` construction. But why use this construction when we have `list.isEmpty()` method...

Comment: Be careful if/when you change this - a list can be initialized and empty - but if you try list.isEmpty() on a null list - you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: *"But why use this construction when we have `list.isEmpty()` method..."* Because if you use `list.isEmpty()` on a `list` variable for which `list == null` is true, it'll throw a `NullPointerException`. The two checks are fundamentally, completely, different.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The first tells you whether the `list` variable has been assigned a List instance or not.

The second tells you if the List referenced by the `list` variable is empty.
If `list` is null, the second line will throw a `NullPointerException`.

If you want to so something only when the list is empty, it is safer to write :

```
if (list != null && list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

If you want to do something if the list is either null or empty, you can write :

```
if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

If you want to do something if the list is not empty, you can write :

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

Answer (score 20):

Another approach is to use [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

Take a look in method [CollectionUtils.isEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty-java.util.Collection-). It is more concise.

Comment: or CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()

Answer (score 11):

For Spring developers, there's another way to check this with only one condition :

```
    !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(yourList)
```

This allow you to test if list !=null and !list.isEmpty()

PS : should import it from  org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils

Answer (score 3):

`if (list == null)` checks whether the list is `null` or not.

`if (list.isEmpty())` checks whether the list is empty or not. If the list is `null` and if you call `isEmpty()`, then it will give you a `NullPointerException`.

It's better to check whether the list is `null` or not first, and then check if it is empty or not.

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
    // do your code here
}
```