# Have a problem saving a List using shared Preferences (Still need help)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

So I was sitting for around two days trying to save a small list using shared preferences. In the code below you can see a many loops which I know isn't very efficient but they work fine for my case so no need to look into them. After I finish using the loops for my algorithm I want to save the output for next time usage. The list which I want to save is "list5". I tried saving it like this but it didn't work out for me.
Also I have a problem with ".isNotEmpty" returning a null error.

Thank you in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> people1;
  List<bool> peoplePres;
  Result({this.people1, this.peoplePres});
  List<String> lastPres;
  void initState() {
    lastZakif();
  }

  void lastZakif() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    lastPres = (prefs.getStringList('lastPres') ?? 0);
  }

  void _loadingNew(List<String> list5) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    lastPres = list5;
    await prefs.setStringList('lastPres', lastPres);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = 0; //count for how many people are here
    int count2 = 1; //count for the new order
    int count4 = 0; //count for last schedule
    List<int> list1 = new List(people1.length); //List with the algorithm
    List<int> list2 = new List(people1.length); //List with the new order
    List<String> list4 = new List(people1.length); // for loading last schedule
    if (lastPres.isNotEmpty==true) {
      for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
        //loading the last schedule and adding people if neccesary part 1
        for (int j = 0; j < people1.length; j++) {
          if (people1[j] == lastPres[i]) {
            list4[count4] = lastPres[i];
            count4++;
          }
        }
      }
      bool check1 = false; //true if person exists
      for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
        //loading the last schedule and adding people if neccesary part 2

        for (int j = 0; j < people1.length; j++) {
          if (people1[i] == list4[j]) {
            check1 = true;
          }
        }
        if (check1 == false) {
          list4[count4] = people1[i];
          count4++;
          check1 = false;
        }
      }
      people1 = list4;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      //counting People that are here
      if (peoplePres[i] == true) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == people1.length) {
      count2 = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // Declaring a list which will be the index for the next Zkifut
      list1[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      //Applying the algorithm
      int num1 = count ~/ 3;
      if (count % 3 == 2) {
        num1 += 1;
      }
      list1[i] = list1[i] + num1 - count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // making the new schedule for absent people but starting with 0
      if (peoplePres[i] == false) {
        list2[i] = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // makeing the new schedule pos num
      if ((list1[i] >= 0) && (peoplePres[i] == true)) {
        list2[i] = count2;
        count2++;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // makeing the new schedule neg num
      if ((list1[i] < 0) && (peoplePres[i] == true)) {
        list2[i] = count2;
        count2++;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      // makeing the new schedule for absent people
      if ((peoplePres[i] == false) && (list2[i]) != 0) {
        list2[i] = count2;
        count2++;
      }
    }

    int count3 = 0;
    List<String> list3 = new List(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      if (peoplePres[list2[i]] == true) {
        list3[count3] = people1[list2[i]];
        count3++;
      }
    }
    List<String> list5 = new List(people1.length); // for saving algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < people1.length; i++) {
      list5[i] = people1[list2[i]];

    }

    _loadingNew(list5);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Result',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: count,
          itemBuilder: (context, value) {
            return Card(
              color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
              elevation: 3,
              child: Container(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Text('${value + 1}'),
                  title: Text(list3[value]
                      //people1[value],
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can save your `list` in `SharedPreferences` as below:

```
void _loadingNew(List<String> list5) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list5);
        editor.putString(key, json);
        editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!

  }
```

Reference : https://gist.github.com/WrathChaos/5f39e3ce3874a049d25e2ca8958d18b6

Also about `isNotEmpty()`
As per answer given by @gprasant [Check whether a string is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

The `isNotEmpty()` checks only that the input parameter is

1. not null
2. not the Empty String ("")

Best way to check if the list is empty or not is:

If you want to so something only when the list is empty, it is safer to write :

```
if (list != null && list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

If you want to do something if the list is either null or empty, you can write :

```
if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

If you want to do something if the list is not empty, you can write :

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) { do something }
```

Reference : [Two ways to check if a list is empty - differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089215/two-ways-to-check-if-a-list-is-empty-differences)

Hope that helps.

Comment: why should I use ArrayList and whats the difference ?

Comment: You see I only need to save a String List which is no problem for using shared preferences I don't think there is a reason to use arrayList

Comment: You're right @Dan7nm you can use list as well, for more reference on this see this page - http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/
They have shown how to save data in Sharedpreference using list. Let me know if you still have any queries.

Comment: Just for knowledge, refer this page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903145/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-arraylist
 for answer on difference between list and arraylist and what you could achieve implementing both.

Comment: @Dan7nm Did my Answer help you?

Comment: Not really, it only converts to array list but the result is the same .

Comment: Did you manage to refer this http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/ as it should help you saving data as list in Sharedpreferences.